# RuntimeException:Unable to start activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I just recently started getting this error. My app worked fine until recently.

This is the logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gasser.yasseen.loginapp/com.gasser.yasseen.loginapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
```

Here is my mainactivity:

```
    public static PrefConfig prefConfig;
    public static APIinterface apIinterface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        prefConfig= new PrefConfig(this);
        apIinterface= APIClient.getAPIClient().create(apIinterface.getClass());
        if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container)!=null)
        {
           if(savedInstanceState!=null)
           {
              return;
           }
            if(prefConfig.ReadLoginStatus())
            {
               getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,new WelcomeFragment()).commit();
            }

            else{
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,new LoginFragment()).commit();
            }

        }
    }


    @Override
    public void performRegister() {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new RegisterFragment()).addToBackStack("null").commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void performLogin(String name) {

    }
}
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing object in its own initialization:

```
apIinterface= APIClient.getAPIClient().create(apIinterface.getClass());
```

Change it to:

```
apIinterface= APIClient.getAPIClient().create(APIinterface.class);
```

The first example cannot be done due to order of command evaluation which is:

1. apIiterface.getClass() -> error because this object was not even initialized
2. create()
3. assign -> this is the point where the object is assigned to this reference variable

Always read the stacktrace from bottom to up - the most concrete exceptions are mostly in bottom and that is the place where you will find your error